# Read and parse a Json File in C# in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json

Here is the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class csharpfile:MonoBehaviour{

    public void LoadJson()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);


        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int millis;
        public string stamp;
        public DateTime datetime;
        public string light;
        public float temp;
        public float vcc;
    }
}
```

Now i want to parse the file content (file.json)

```
[ 
    { "millis": "1000", 
      "stamp": "1273010254", 
      "datetime": "2010/5/4 21:57:34", 
      "light": "333", 
      "temp": "78.32", 
      "vcc": "3.54" }, 
]
```

how would i print content on screen after file parsing and how to write in file .do help.....

Comment: *how would i print content on screen after file parsing and how to write in file .do help.....*. What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity)

Answer (score 4):

for printing the `deserialized` value:

```
                    string json = file.ReadToEnd();
                    List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.millis);
                    }
```

for writing/serializing:

```
                var serObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Item
                {
                    //assign values here
                });
```

Or

```
                var stm = new MemoryStream();
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                {
                    var ser = new JsonSerializer();
                    ser.Serialize(sw, new Item());
                }
```

Comment: THANKS for your Time                     But there is an error                                  Error CS0103: The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: install `Newtonsoft.Json` from NuGet

Comment: Or just use the built-in JsonUtility.FromJson(string json)